# Html2Canvas render full div content

Tags: angular, pdf, html2canvas

I'm trying to use html2canvas to print to pdf the content of a div:

```
<div #printSection>
  some content
</div>
```

I have a function that serves this purpose:

```
public print(el: ElementRef, name: string, orientation: string = 'l') {
    const doc = new jsPDF(orientation, 'px', 'a4');
    html2Canvas(el.nativeElement).then(
      (canvas) => {
        const img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const ratio = canvas.height / canvas.width;
        const w = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
        const h = w * ratio;
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 10, w, h);
        doc.save(name);
      }
    );
  }
```

where I pass the element ref as parameter and it exports its content as pdf. 
The problem is: this works fine as long as I use a large screen, when my screen gets smaller and the div is not rendered as a whole but it has scroll bars on the sides this function doesn't print the whole div content but it is limited to the visibile section.

Is there a workaround for this issure. I need this print to be independant from the screen it is launched because this app is meant to run on tablets as well.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1):

html2pdf could probably solve your problem. It's built on top of jsPDF and html2canvas.
https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js
Give it a try.